# PHP text messages suddenly sending from a different address

Tags: php, text, vps

I have a website that sends out text messages from the server. I'm using PHP for it:

```
$headers = "From: " . "Business Name <info@businessdomain.com>" . "\r\n";
$result = @mail( $to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Up until yesterday, the FRM: was always "Business Name" in the text message.

Suddenly, I'm now getting reports that FRM: is coming in as username@173.222.21.166 where username is my actual FTP account username (real IP not provided of course)!!

I definitely don't want to expose my FTP username. Is there something that would determine the FRM: name other than what I have set? I haven't changed the script at all... and suddenly it has changed.

UPDATE: using PHP mail not SMS Gateway

Comment: I have it set with a cron script. I didn't set it to a phone number.. I can't remember why but I'm not sure a number worked for the reply. I used an email address because the replys came through that fine that way.

Comment: I don’t think the OP is sending SMS/text messages – after all, they are just using `mail` …

Comment: PHP mail... free 99!

Comment: Did this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25345434/1342440 not solve your issue?

Comment: @Brian link takes me to this same thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a command line parameters to php's [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function, one of which is from.

`mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-finfo@businessdomain.com');`

Note the `-f` directly infront of your from address

Comment: Brian, will the solution you gave still show "Business Name" as opposed to the actual email address?

Comment: Set your headers as is, just add the additional parameter

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the mail server on the local machine or the mail configuration on the local machine. There are certain settings, which can prevent faking the FROM header and substituting it by the actual user running the program that sends the mail.

I recommend checking the mail config for php and for the system itself.

Comment: php `mail` is used and `username@173.222.21.166` is an email address which overwrites the given email address. That's related to mail config all before anything is passed to any SMS gateway.